# Azure Blob Storage V2 does not deliver content-disposition header any more

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, content-disposition

I have a question about the "content-disposition" blob property of a file in Azure Blog Storage V2.

I configured this property of my file howto-201901.pdf as "attachment; filename=howto.pdf" with Azure Storage Explorer 1.6.2 (see screenshot) asn in Azure Portal. The property is set on file, but not delivered as header info on downloading.

With previous storage V1, was it no problem. If I downloaded the file howto-2010901.pdf, was the http header content-disposition set and the browser downloaded the file like my configuration howto-pdf.

But since 2 or 3 month, maybe since my upgrade to storage V2, doesn't work this feature. The browser download the file with the original name.

Is there anyone, who has information for me to solve this behavior?

Best Tino

[image]

Comment: I found the reason and a solution for this behavior.
I guess the content-disposition http header information will no longer set, if the url has no SAS token.
Add the SAS token and you win. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1

Answer (score 6):

**Content-Disposition** header in response is not sent when the download URL is not authenticated. For the client to receive **Content-Disposition**

1. Create an SAS token with limited access.
2. Append it to blob download link.

Comment: Do you know if this is stated anywhere in the documentation? Or was this figured out via trial-and-error?

Comment: By a lot of trail and error @Matt

Comment: "Append it to blob download link." what does this mean exactly?

Comment: @Mattwmaster58 I don't remember clearly. But I think I meant to add a URL parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution and worked for me.

Instead of creating a new policy, can you take also an existing policy from your blob storage. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1

```
    private Uri GetDownloadUri(CloudBlockBlob blob)
    {
        try
        {
            // Return the SAS token.
            var query = GenerateSASQueryString(blob);

            UriBuilder newUri = new UriBuilder(blob.Uri)
            {
                Query = query
            };

            return newUri.Uri;
        }
        catch (UriFormatException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        return blob.Uri;
    }

    private string GenerateSASQueryString(CloudBlockBlob blob)
    {
        if (blob == null)
            return null;

        // Create a new access policy for the account.
        SharedAccessBlobPolicy policy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy
        {
            Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(24),
            SharedAccessStartTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
        };

        // Return the SAS token.
        var query = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy);
        return query;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issue, but I'm very confused about .NET SDKs and the `SharedAccessBlobPolicy`.

I'm using `Azure.Storage.Blobs` version `12.4.1` SDK for managing storage. Is it possible to use it to set `SharedAccessBlobPolicy`, or am I supposed to do it different way? I tried to look into documentation, but it is not really helpful, I could find just information about `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob` SDK version `11` which is considered legacy and deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the missing content-disposition header for me without requiring a shared access signature:

```
// Only need to run this code once for the storage account.
Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobServiceClient client = ...

var properties = client.GetProperties().Value;
properties.DefaultServiceVersion = "2023-08-03"; // Latest service version at time of writing.
client.SetProperties(properties);
```

Credit: https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/fixing-azure-blob-storage-content-disposition